# Owl-carousel slide from left to right using animate.css plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I am using a slider plugin called [Owl Carousel 2](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html).

I am using [Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) as well.

Now my issue is that `animateIn: 'slideInLeft'` is working but `animateOut` is not working according to my need.

I need to slide my image like this :

https://www.w3schools.com/booTsTrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel2&stacked=h

**Note** : it's sliding from right to left but I need it to slide the opposite way (from left to right).

Would you kindly help me out with this issue?

```js
$('#GallerySlider').owlCarousel({
  dots: false,
  loop: true,
  margin: 10,
  nav: true,
  autoplay: true,
  animateIn: 'slideInLeft',
  animateOut: 'slideInLeft',
  responsive: {
    0: {
      items: 1
    },
    600: {
      items: 1
    },
    1000: {
      items: 1
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.7.0/animate.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

<section>
  <div class="Gallery">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="GallerySlider">
      <div class="item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTlkGqPJPf0tsgfoEVS32fPXDJRQ2mxk5ioOnFhrgDsCKnSpPve"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486406146926-c627a92ad1ab?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTvmsPDO1qCfjUNpAKgj5uBfuuDohdAMa1BTIeHGn-FmN6A3lOu"></div>
    </div>

  </div>

</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the editing. @Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `animateIn` to `slideInRight` and `animateOut` to `slideOutLeft`.

The incoming slide will slide from the right to the left and the outgoing one will slide out from the right to the left.

If you want the opposite effect, set `animateIn` to `slideInLeft` and set `animateOut` to `slideOutRight`.

If you need true 'right to left' support, set `rtl` to `true` in your Owl Carousel settings. See this [demo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/rtl.html) to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, It's working perfectly. I was confused. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)